# Употребление причастий и причастных оборотов, деепричастий и деепричастных оборотов

Tags: синтаксис

**Найдите и объясните ошибки в употреблении причастий и причастных оборотов, исправьте предложения.**

1. Прочитанный курс лекций им не был издан, как это обычно практиковалось, поскольку освещенные вопросы на лекциях были достаточно полно изложены в незадолго до этого опубликованной книге.
2. Докладчик усиленно готовится к заседанию, состоявшемуся через неделю.
3. Не могущие устареть произведения композитора будут жить всегда, помогая людям мира найти общий язык.

**Возможные варианты:**

1. Курс лекций, прочитанный им, не был издан, как это обычно практиковалось. Большинство вопросов, освещенных на лекциях, были достаточно полно изложены в книге, опубликованной незадолго до этого.
   **Объяснение:** Нагромождение причастий и причастных оборотов создает неблагозвучие. Определяемое слово не должно разрывать причастный оборот.
2. Докладчик усиленно готовится к заседанию, **которое состоится/состоящемуся** (можно ли так употреблять?) через неделю. 
   **Объяснение:** согласуется в соответствии со временем. Если **готовится** (наст. время), то не может он делать это к уже **состоявшемуся** (пр. время) заседанию.
3. Не **устаревающие** произведения композитора будут жить всегда, помогая людям мира найти общий язык.
   **Объяснение:** В первоначальном варианте звучит ужасно, с синтаксической точки зрения не могу пояснить.

**Найдите и объясните ошибки в употреблении деепричастий и деепричастных оборотов, исправьте предложения.**

1. Изучая на месте практический опыт горьковчан по повышению качества и надежности промышленных изделий, было принято решение подробно рассказать об этом на страницах журнала с целью его распространения на другие промышленные предприятия страны.
2. Сравнивая одно с другим, еще отчетливее проявляются фальшь и лицемерие этой агрессивной политики.
3. Заняв первое место в побочном турнире, юный шахматист приглашен в главный турнир.
4. Серьезное общение, стоя за высоким столиком, вряд ли возможно.

**Возможные варианты:**

1. Было принято решение подробно рассказать на страницах журнала о практическом опыте горьковчан по повышению качества и надежности промышленных изделий. Целью решения является распространение опыта горьковчан на другие промышленные предприятия страны.
   **Объяснение:** Нагромождение деепричастий создает неблагозвучие. Присутствует двусмысленность: распространять на другие предприятия опыт горьковчан или же журнал? В соответствии с этим нужно исправить предложение.
2. Фальшь и лицемерие этой агрессивной политики еще отчетливее проявляются при сравнении одного с другим.
3. Юный шахматист, заняв первое место в побочном турнире, был приглашен в главный турнир.
4. Серьезное общение вряд ли возможно, стоя за высоким столиком.
   Стоя за высоким столиком, вряд ли возможно серьезно общаться.

Господа эксперты, помогите разобраться.

Answer (score 3):

1.Курс лекций,прочитанный им, не был издан, как это обычно практиковалось, поскольку  вопросы, освещенные на лекциях, были достаточно полно изложены в книге, опубликованной незадолго до этого .

2.Докладчик усиленно готовился к заседанию, которое состоится через неделю.(причастие не образуется от глаголов будущего времени)

3.Нестареющие произведения композитора будут жить всегда, помогая людям мира найти общий язык.

1.После изучения на месте практического опыта горьковчан по повышению качества и надежности промышленных изделий было принято решение подробно рассказать об этом на страницах журнала с целью его распространения на другие промышленные предприятия страны.(Исполнитель  основного и добавочного действия должен быть один)

2.При сравнении одного с другим еще отчетливее проявляются фальшь и лицемерие этой агрессивной политики.

3.Когда юный шахматист занял первое место в побочном турнире, он был приглашен в главный турнир.

4.Серьезное общение стоящих за высоким столиком  вряд ли возможно.Или Ваш вариант:Стоя за высоким столиком, вряд ли возможно серьезно общаться.

Comment: Первое. Причастие будущего времени, если уж припекает, можно образовать аналитически, тем более что скромные дозы архаизмов в канцелярите допустимы.
Докладчик усиленно готовился к заседанию, имеющему состояться через неделю.
 Второе. С целью распространения изученного на месте практического опыта горьковчан по повышению качества и надёжности промышленных изделий на другие промышленные предприятия страны было принято решение подробно рассказать о нём на страницах журнала.   
Так можно уйти от неоднозначности "распространять на другие предприятия опыт горьковчан или же журнал?"

Comment: 1.Вряд ли "припекает". Обычное задание по культуре речи. Студент должен обнаружить ошибку, связанную с образованием причастий. Он просто должен знать, что причастие не образуется от безличных глаголов и глаголов ирреального действия - повелит. и условного наклонения и буд. времени. 2.Согласна, можно и так, только всё равно громоздко.Требовалось устранить ошибку в построении предложений с деепричастным оборотом - её устранили, можно добавить:"...решение подробно рассказать об этом опыте на страницах журнала с целью его распространения ..."

Answer (score 1):

В комментарий не помещается, приходится использовать форму ответа.

> "...решение подробно
> рассказать об этом опыте на страницах
> журнала с целью его распространения ..."

- остаётся замеченная автором вопроса неуклюжесть выражения: "с целью **его** распространения" - распространения журнала? Опыта? 
  Оно, конечно, каламбур хорош. То ли опыт горьковчан нуждается в рассказе о нём на страницах журнала, то ли журнал сам больше нуждается в этом рассказе с целью собственного распространения. Но если это не обдуманная ирония, "журнал" и "распостранение" лучше, мне кажется, развести по углам, нет?

Comment: Да я согласна, что Ваш вариант яснее,просто,как правило, авторы этих заданий не требуют перестраивать всё предложение, они хотят видеть исправление УКАЗАННОЙ грамматической ошибки. Был случай в колледже, студентка перестроила всё предложение, ей не засчитали, сказали:"Это уже Ваше предложение, а не предложенное.Вам нужно было исправить конструкцию с деепричастным оборотом, а не всё предложение".Не хотелось бы навредить автору вопроса.